# How does YouTube fetch data from a data center located far away?

Tags: video, youtube

As I heard that there are multiple YouTube data centers located in different places. And data replication is not so high. So I just wondered, if a person always requires a video stored at the data center located far away, how does YouTube fetch such video? Do they fetch and store a copy of all these videos in the nearest data center? Or just fetch at each time when the video required? I am a beginner in this area, and just curious about that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly all Video services use a Content Delivery Network (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

These, in very simple terms, are a solution which cache the content, video in this case, near the edge of the network so end users don't have to wait for delivery from a single point.

Many CDN's operate a pull model - this means that the first user in a particular area actually does 'pull' the content from the original server, but all subsequent users will pull from the local cache.